# Query MYSQL não ordena corretamente

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-select, order-by

Olá. Tenho a seguinte query:

```sql
    SELECT * 
      from usuarios_cursos_matriculados 
 LEFT JOIN cursos ON cursos.cedoc_doc_id_fk = usuarios_cursos_matriculados.cedoc_doc_id_fk 
 LEFT JOIN cedoc_doc ON cedoc_doc.cedoc_doc_id = cursos.cedoc_doc_id_fk 
 LEFT JOIN cursos_aulas ON cursos.cedoc_doc_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ultimas_aulas order by data_realizada DESC) AS c ON c.id_curso = cedoc_doc.cedoc_doc_id 
  GROUP BY cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk DESC
```

Neste caso, a tabela deveria puxar os cursos nos quais o usuário está matriculado contidos na tabela `usuarios_cursos_matriculados`, a primeira aula do curso, contida na tabela `cursos_aulas` e a última aula visualizada, contida na tabela ultimas_aulas. A query está funcionando pela metade, ela puxa corretamente os cursos matriculados e a primeira aula de cada curso, porém, ela não ordena corretamente as últimas aulas visualizadas pelo usuário nos cursos selecionados. Ao invés dela ordenar de ordem decrescente de acordo com a coluna `data_realizada`, que contém a data na qual a data foi visualizada, ela ordena em ordem crescente. Quando eu removo o group by, ela ordena corretamente, porém, os registros ficam duplicados.

Como eu poderia corrigir o funcionamento dessa query?

Comment: Creio que aqui: `GROUP BY cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk DESC` você pulou a cláusula ORDER BY`.

Comment: A consulta está correta? Só a ordem que está errada? Você quer somente a última aula ou todas ordenadas?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve adicionar a clausura Order by no final da consulta segue como ficaria:

```
    SELECT * 
      from usuarios_cursos_matriculados 
 LEFT JOIN cursos ON cursos.cedoc_doc_id_fk = usuarios_cursos_matriculados.cedoc_doc_id_fk 
 LEFT JOIN cedoc_doc ON cedoc_doc.cedoc_doc_id = cursos.cedoc_doc_id_fk 
 LEFT JOIN cursos_aulas ON cursos.cedoc_doc_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ultimas_aulas order by data_realizada DESC) AS c ON c.id_curso = cedoc_doc.cedoc_doc_id 
  GROUP BY cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk DESC
  ORDER BY c.data_realizada DESC
```

Comment: Dessa maneira ele até ordena pela data, porém, ainda puxa o primeiro registro de cada curso, ao invés do último.

Comment: VocÊ pode adicionar mais order by em sequencia, ex:
neste caso foi:
**ORDER BY c.data_realizada DESC**
voce pode ir adicionando com uma virgula, ficando assim:
**ORDER BY c.data_realizada, (outra coluna para ordernar), (outra se quiser), (Etc) DESC**